# How to list possible style options for `clang-format` using the clang-format C++ API (or, how to import clang module in simple script)?

Tags: c++, clang, clang-format

There are a ton of style option properties defined at https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html but they don't seem to be programmatically accessible, or at least printable through the command line. Is there a way to list them all using the C++ API so I don't have to try and webscrape that page for the list of options (and their possible values)? I have some experience with C, but not C++, so not sure how I can write a quick script to print these to the console (ideally as JSON, but as some ad-hoc text output is fine too).

The main code I think which defines the styles is at [https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/main/clang/lib/Format/Format.cpp](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/2bb511e277e501d3faa0f2da0d1c98ea0b515507/clang/lib/Format/Format.cpp#L511). *What would a quick script to at least load these into the `main` function scope for a C++ script be*, so I can run `clang++ export-formats.cpp` from the CLI and have it print the formats? Just getting me started at how to load the format into the appropriate scope would be enough, and then I can figure out how to iterate through the styles and such if that works, and print them.

I am stuck at the beginning basically:

```
#include <clang/Format/Format.h>

int main() {
  // Prints hello world
  cout << "Hello World";

  return 0;
}
```

Getting:

```
tmp/export-formats.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'clang/Format/Format.h' file not found
#include <clang/Format/Format.h>
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

What I would like to export is found in here:

```
template <> struct MappingTraits<FormatStyle> {
  static void mapping(IO &IO, FormatStyle &Style) {
    // When reading, read the language first, we need it for getPredefinedStyle.
    IO.mapOptional("Language", Style.Language);
    ...
```

The `IO.mapOptional("Language"`, I would want to put language, and the corresponding options defined in `Style.Language`. So the output for that line would be something like:

```
{ "option": "Language", values: ["c++", "c", ...] }
```

The `Style` is defined under [Format.h](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/0cc31579e0b690e974163da4077a40b49bfc1ebc/clang/include/clang/Format/Format.h#L55).

If anything, just looking for this (if it's too much work to implement a full script):

- Example of how to import the files, to run with the `clang++` CLI?

From there I can tinker around if anything to figure out how to export the keys and values from the actual imports. But the end goal if possible would be to print out everything listed in https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html , and by that I mean:

```
$ clang++ export-formats.cpp
[
  { "option": "BasedOnStyle", "type": "enum", "values": ["Google", "LLVM", ...] },
  { "option": "AccessModifierOffset", "type": "integer" },
  { "option": "AlignAfterOpenBracket", "type": "enum", "values": ["Align", "DontAlign", ...] },
  ...
]
```

I am on a Mac if that matters, having [installed llvm project with HomeBrew](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/llvm). But I also have a Docker linux setup available locally, so whatever works.

In learning how to do this, I will at the same time learn how to get started working in C++! That would be great :) If it's not possible for some reason, might just have to resort to webscraping, or scraping [`ClangFormatStyleOptions.rst`](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/18734f606635f4f4270f911b68060890ce3dd94a/clang/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.rst#L860). But it *seems* possible with my limited knowledge, using the C++ API.

Comment: I don't know about the C++ interface, but you can use `--dump-config` on the command line.

Comment: @JosephThomson can you show the full command por favor?

Comment: `clang-format --dump-config`. But I just noticed you want all the possible options, and this just gives you the current full config.

Comment: In order to `#include <clang/Format/Format.h>` you need to supply `-isystem path-to-your-llvm-project-clone/clang/include` when compiling - but you most probably need to link with some library too

Comment: @JosephThomson yeah it looks like `clang-format --dump-config` just gives me the cpp config, not all the options and possible values.

Comment: @TedLyngmo do you happen to know the exact configuration/options to pass to the command, given I installed with HomeBrew?

Comment: I don't know the exactly what options you need unfortunately. What I would do: **1** `git clone git@github.com:llvm/llvm-project.git` **2** `cd llvm-project/clang/tools/clang-format`  **3** Figure out how to build `clang-format` from that source (it's cmake so it shouldn't be too hard). **4** Copy and modify the source to spit out the information you need. The `clang-format` binary is just a frontend for the formatting library in llvm but it should serve as a good starting point for interacting with that library.